# How to check for null values with Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I'm having an SQL table Countries, with CountryId and StateId. StateId can be null, as not all countries have States.
I'd like to check if the combination of country/state exists in the table. If I have the country "NL" and state NULL in the table, and I use the following query where countryId = "NL" and stateId = null:

```
return await conn.ExecuteScalarAsync<bool>(@"SELECT COUNT(*)
                                             FROM [dbo].[Countries]
                                             WHERE [CountryId] = @CountryId
                                             AND [StateId] = @StateId",
                                             new { countryId, stateId });
```

It will return false. I expected a true response. Could someone explain this behaviour and what is the best approach to solve this?

Comment: That is how SQL works. It is nothing to do with Dapper, or C# or .NET. If you do `[StateId] = NULL` then you won't get any results - check it for yourself in SSMS (or your SQL client of choice). You need to include `AND [StateId] = @StateId` _only_ if  `stateId` is not null (or check the answer below if you are explicitly interested in it _being_ `null`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not a Dapper issue. Comparing anything to NULL with the = operator will [usually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) return false. You will have to use "is null" for comparison, ie

```
AND [StateId] is null
```

(at least on SQL Server). That means of course that your query will have to look differently in case stateid is null.

Comment: Perhaps some C# example code may be in order?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM [dbo].[Countries]
       WHERE [CountryId] = @CountryId
       AND ([StateId] IS NULL OR ([StateId] IS NOT NULL AND [StateId] = @StateId))
```

It will check if `StateId` is `null`, then only the 'CountryId' will be checked for those countries with no state, if `StateId` is not `null`, then `StateId` would be checked too

Comment: `[StateId] IS NOT NULL AND` is not needed. It makes the query longer with no meaningful benefit (i.e. it doesn't impact the results). Also, if you pass in a value of `@StateId`, it will return values with that value **or null** which I suspect is not what the OP expected.